# Change account for crashlytics not working

Tags: crashlytics-android, fabric.io

We have an app already register on fabrics , crashes are reported on that account without any issue but now we want to change account for this app for new release but its not getting changed i.e app is not visible on new account   instead new version of app is visible on old account.

Anyone can help me with this.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using new account you can continue using same account by changing primary email here https://fabric.io/settings/notifications/emails. You can change every single information including name, organization, mobile number, etc. You will be able to login with email address you make primary after change.